# Silencing bash's unalias when there's nothing to unalias

Tags: bash, alias

I have access to a couple of remote accounts, which I mount via sshfs in subdirs of $HOME/SSHFS. In order to remind me that I'm not working with local files, I have set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to a function `prmt_cmd`, where I set a different `$PS1` if `$PWD` matches `$HOME/SSHFS*`. Now, to add a little extra protection, I'd like to add the `-i` flags automatically to the `rm`, `mv` and `cp` commands whenever I'm in a subdir of `$HOME/SSHFS`. So I ended up with something like

```
function prmt_cmd () {
if [[ $PWD == $HOME/SSHFS* ]] ; then
    PS1=some prompt
    alias rm='rm -I'
    alias mv='mv -i'
    alias cp='cp -i'
else
    # Reset the PS1, remove aliases
    PS1=my default prompt
    unalias rm mv cp
fi
}
```

(In the actual definition, I do some other stuff, but this is irrelevant.) However, `unalias` complains when the aliases do not exist, meaning that I get three error messages before each prompt when I'm not in SSHFS/*. `unalias` doesn't seem to have a switch to silence it. So my question is: Is there a better way to achieve what I want? Maybe I'm simply Doing It (Completely) Wrong.

In case it's relevant, `$BASH_VERSION = 4.1.5(1)-release` on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just redirect the output.

```
unalias rm mv cp >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: `&>/dev/null` will take out both birds with one stone.

Comment: just redirect stderr is sufficient `2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

In bash you could do the following to *unalias* an alias only if it exists, for example `rm`:

```
[ -n "`alias -p | grep '^alias rm='`" ] && unalias rm
```

Another idea would be to overwrite the alias, even it if exists:

```
alias rm='/bin/rm'
```

Answer (score 0):

`alias name >/dev/null 2>&1  &&  unalias name`

Instead of redirecting the output of `unalias`, this quietly tests for the presence of the alias, then deletes it if found.

This avoids aborting a script running `set -e`, unless something actually goes wrong doing the `unalias`. It also does not eat the diagnostic message from `unalias` when something *does* go wrong.

It is also simpler than parsing the output of `alias -p` with child processes.